# Array of objects vs new

Tags: c++, arrays, temporary

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
  A(int d) : y(d) {}

  int y;
};

int main(void) {
  A d[3] = {A(0), A(1), A(2)};
  std::cout << d[1].y << std::endl;
};
```

I'm working on a project for university. I'm instructed **not** to use an object array and instantiate each element with a temporary object of my class - so something like the above code is a no-no. Instead, it's recommended we use a an array of type `A*` and then use new on each element so that we create an object and make each element point to it.

So we'd have something like this:

```cpp
A* d[3];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
d[i]=new A(i);
```

However, I don't quite understand the difference in practice when compared to the first version. As far as I understand in the first version we we create the three temporary objects (which are rvalues) using the constructor and then assign them to the array. After the assignment ends, the temporary is destroyed and its values are copied to the array. In the second version, we have the advantage of being able to delete what `d[]` points to but disregarding that, what is the drawback of using the first method?

EDIT:

```cpp
class B{
public:
A a1[3];
}
```

Assuming my initial definition is followed by this (A isn't default constructible, is something like this impossible? So in that case I can't an array of objects and I instead have to resort to a pointer array of type `A*` and then use `new`, as my only resort.

Comment: Your version is better, because it avoids (apparently) needless heap allocations and pointers. Unfortunately the standard of C++ teaching is not very high.

Comment: The first version allocates memory on the stack, while the second allocates memory on the heap. Do you understand the difference between the stack and the heap?

Comment: Regarding the follow up. The generally best alternative is to use `std::vector<A> a1;` vector does not require it's type to be default constructable.

Comment: I have omitted some crucial information regarding my issue, I think now it's more clear (not meaning to give a bad name to my professor, I have better described the reason I think we shouldn't use the temporary objects)

Comment: Also @john unfortunately I'm currently not allowed to use STL containers, so is the EDIT impossible to use therefore? So I can only use `A* a1[3]` as the field in my `class B`

Comment: @pol There are no temporary objects. Your understanding that `A d[3] = {A(0), A(1), A(2)};` constructs and then discards temporary objects is incorrect.

Comment: @pol You can use a technique called *placement new* to get around the problems of not having a default constructor. This is what `std::vector` uses in it's implementation. But yes the editted code, exactly as it is, does require a default constructor.

Comment: I don't quite understand your second to last comment. Aren't A(0),A(1),A2) temporary objects? They are copied to the array (using the copy ctor) and then each temporary is destroyed but their values live in the array. And as to your last comment, I am therefore 'forced' to use a pointer array in this case? (no STL containers as I said) or is there a 'cleaner' way? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Array of pointers -> memory allocation when you create an object and assign it to the pointer. Array of 1000 pointers with 1 element inside = 1x the memory.

Array of objects -> memory allocation when you create an array. Array of 1000 with 1 element inside = 1000x the memory.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) `A d[3]`, it creates a built-in array (or C-style, plain, naked array...) which contains (three) elements of type `A`, these elements live on the stack (according to your code).

2 ) `A* d[3];`, it creates a built-in array which contains (three) pointers to elements of type `A` (or they should). It doesn't mean that the pointed element is of type `A`, it's developer's task to create those elements, and you can do it in two ways, using the stack (as before):

```
A element;
...
d[0] = &element;
```

or using the heap (with `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]`):

```
d[0] = new A;
...
delete d[0];
```

---

Side effects of the second option; you may point to an already destroyed element (i.e. the element is out of scope), hence potential seg fault; you may loose the pointer to the allocated memory (i.e. the array of pointers is out of scope and the allocated memory has not been released), hence memory leak.

However, an advantage is that you can use lazy initialisation (you don't pay for what you don't use). If you don't need an `A` object in `d[2]` (or pointed by), why should you create it and waste memory? And here [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) arise, they make your life easier allowing you to allocate memory only when you need it, reducing the risk of seg faults (worth it to mention [std::weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)), memory leaks,  etc:

```
    std::unique_ptr<A> d[3];
    d[0] = std::make_unique<A>(); // Call make_unique when you need it
```

---

But still a bit nasty, the built-in arrays are good but may be much better under some circumstances. It is hard to add or remove elements, iterate, get the size, access to the tail/head, etc... And that's why [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) are quite useful, i.e. [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (where its size doesn't have to be known at compilation time):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr< A> > d(3);
```

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<A,3> > d;
```

Comment: Thank you! but as I said, I can't use STL containers (it's a uni assignment) so I think I am forced to use a pointer array within my class (of type  `A*`) since my `A` isn't default constructible. So I can do `a1[i]=A(0)` if `A` is default constructible (since a1[i] would have already been created) but if I not (like in my case) I'd have to create a pointer array and give each element the return of `new(constructor arguments)`?

Comment: Yes you can, but as stated before, you'll have to ensure that the array of pointers and the pointed elements have the same scope, in order to be able to ```delete``` the elements before the array of pointers is destroyed.

Comment: Yep, got it. But is my reasoning as to why I can't do `a1[i]=...` in this case correct? (that a1[i] can't be default constructed)

Answer (score -1):

There are no advantages whatsoever to the following code in C++:

```
A* d[3];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
d[i]=new A(i);
```

In fact, you shouldn't write it at all.

Your solution with a locally-declared temporary array is valid, but has the significant limitation of requiring that the number of elements in the array be a *compile-time constant* (i.e., known ahead of time).

If you need to have an array with a dynamic number of elements, known only at run time, then you should use a `std::vector`, which performs the `new` allocation automatically. That is the idiomatic way of working with dynamically-allocated arrays in C++.

Comment: There is an additional common situation where the local array isn't feasible. Stack frame is pretty small usually and if the array is large and/or each element uses significant memory - that solution will cause stack corruption